# Unicode conversion of double quotes, " and ”

Tags: html, unicode, query-string

I have a text field, when i enter a value in it.It is stored in DB, passed through query string.When manually entering a string containing "(double quotes), it is working fine, but when pasting a non 8 bit text as such ”(double quotes), it is not able to uriDecode the string.

I refereed the following link to understand the issue.

http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Comment: What does "not able to uriDecode" mean? What is happening or not happening? What's your code? Any errors? Garbled text?

Comment: when i pass a string suppose java stack "15 overflow.via url is gets converted to java%20stack%20%2215%20overflow.but if instead of double quotes from the keyboard, if i pasted the double quotes as ”(tilted one).The value getting saved in db is java%20stack%20%E2%80%9D15%20overflow not java stack ”15 overflow

Comment: Then Show Your Code! The value doesn't get saved in the DB all by itself, you're doing something wrong in your code. Also specify what programming language you're talking about.

Comment: `%E2%80%9D` is the correct URI encoding for IRI character `”`. But you shouldn't be storing content in your database in URI-encoded form. Try to ensure you are connecting to your database in a Unicode-clean form... impossible to say how without known what your database and programming language are.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - you're going to need to provide more information about the full lifecycle of the process in question. Looks like you're using Java based on your comments, so is this JSP, perhaps a framework? And how is Java talking to your database? To be helpful, more information is needed. As written, it's hard to help you because the source of the error is unclear. With more information we might be able to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about PHP variable passing problem. You didn't provided us a code but if I understand your problem, you enter both " and ” into field but only " is passed to next page. Possible solution is not to use ” or you can use some javascript to automaticly trigger onkeydown event that will automaticly correct text and switch from ” to "

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetext(field_name) {
var myTextField = document.getElementById(field_name).value;
var myTextFieldEdited = myTextField.replace('”', '"');
document.getElementById(field_name).value = myTextFieldEdited;

return;
}
</script>


<form>
<textarea id="text_field" onkeydown="changetext('text_field');" onsubmit="changetext('text_field');"></textarea>
</form>
```

onkeydown is triggered when you are writing text and if you ctrl+c and ctrl+v text on submit should do final check and change to make sure there are no ” in text.